# How to return only one result when making a double await Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Hi I can´t find a solution to my problem of functions in cascade,

**Service A**

```
print(await serviceB.methodA(myParameter));
```

**Service B**

```
async methodA(MyParameter){

            return await methodB(MyParamter).then((value) =>{
                serviceA.methodC(value);
               }

            
         );
    }
```

So the output is

```
undefined
result
```

How I can wait to the second result of the then?? Because when getting undefined is broking my service A

Comment: You didn't return a promise in the first `then` call back. Add the `return` before `serviceA.methodC(......`

Comment: you should return that `Promise` in then callback: `return serviceA.methodC`

Comment: You should not mix `await` with promise chaining `foo().then().then()` Select one method you like better and stick with it ...

Comment: @trincot I edited the question because after hours of trying to solve it I was doing a mess, this is how I tried first, so the problem is how to avoid the first result.

Comment: The `return` is still missing...

Comment: You are not returning anything from `then(value => {....}` thus the final result of `methodA`  is a `Promise<void>`, which if you `await` it resolves to `undefined` what is, what you see printed. If you still have `undefined` after you add `return serivceA.methodC()` show the definition of `methodC`. Maybe you are not returning anything there either ...

Comment: @derpirscher is working adding the return, I just didn't understand why I needed one more return it confused me, thanks. Do you want to ask the question or do I answer it?

Comment: @trincot thanks, working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code structure, you need to return the inner promise.

**Change this:**

```
async methodA(MyParameter){
    return await methodB(MyParamter).then((value) =>{
        serviceA.methodC(value);
    });
}
```

**to this:**

```
async methodA(MyParameter){
    return methodB(MyParamter).then((value) =>{
        return serviceA.methodC(value);
    });
}
```

The result of the `.then()` becomes the resolved value of the promise chain.  Since you weren't returning anything from the `.then()` handler, that resolved value became `undefined`.

---

But, since you're using `async/await`, it is generally better to not also mix `.then()` in the same code so I'd recommend changing to this:

```
async methodA(MyParameter){
    let value = await methodB(MyParamter);
    return serviceA.methodC(value);
}
```